# Start OpenVPN from Java application

Tags: java, vpn, openvpn

Is it even possible to start OpenVPN trough Java application? If it is possible what is the best way to do it so it's cross-platform and works on all platforms that have OpenVPN installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run openvpn with Java like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("openvpn your_config.ovpn");
```

This will run openvpn via the command line. It is cross platform, too, as it will work on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Assuming it's on the PATH, this is cross platform

Comment: True, but doesn’t it install to a place on the path?

Comment: Depends on the installation method

Comment: Is it possible to run without using openvpn client or to create a custom client using java?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to create a VPN client using Java, and yes, there are other clients besides openvpn, but both of those are out of scope of this question.